# Practical use of AJAX Accordion control

Tags: ajax, accordion

The Ajax accordion on my page isn't functioning at all. It displays fine on the page, but I can't seem to expand/collapse the panes when I click on their Headers.

Here's my code (just the HTML portion as I'm not aware of any code behind that is needed):

```
<aj:Accordion runat="server" ID="acMain" SelectedIndex="0"
    FadeTransitions="true"
    TransitionDuration="400"
    FramesPerSecond="40" RequireOpenedPane="false" TabIndex="0"
    SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" HeaderCssClass="acHeader"
    HeaderSelectedCssClass="acHeaderSelected">
    <Panes>
        <aj:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="Panel1">
            <Header>
                ...
            </Header>
            <Content>
                ...
            </Content>
        </aj:AccordionPane>

        <aj:AccordionPane runat="server" ID="Panel2">
            <Header>
                ...
            </Header>
            <Content>
                ...
            </Content>
        </aj:AccordionPane>
    </Panes>
</aj:Accordion>
```

I've checked the [official page for the Accordion](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/Accordion/Accordion.aspx) as well as a number of blogs on the subject (all of which seem to be a copy of the official page with the author's own wording) and according to all of this, I can't see that I've done anything wrong or missed anything out.

Matter of fact, I've checked an Accordion my boss made a while back and my code's basically the same as his (only panel content is different) and he has no code-behind either, so I'm really lost here.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**
After adapting my code [according to a sample](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/ajax-control-toolkit/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-accordion-control) on asp.net, I've managed to collapse the first pane (SelectedIndex 0), but the other one won't expand :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I copied the accordion code from [the asp.net how to page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/ajax-control-toolkit/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-accordion-control) and put my content into the panes, still had no effect.

As it turns out, there was a rogue `</div>` tag in my content that was wrecking the accordion so I recommend that anyone having any similar problems checks their content very thoroughly.

Also, it's worth noting here that as this particular sample worked for me and because I'm telling you to use it if you're having trouble, it's author did leave an incorrectly closed `</p>` tag that might cause problems with your accordion during testing, so watch out for that.